# Extract LAS tool is not working inside a loop?

Tags: arcpy, clip, lidar, arcgis-10.4, error-000732

In order to extract points from a .lasd (here, I call it "x.lasd") by 30 individual polygons, I am using the following code for the `Extract LAS` tool in ArcGIS 10.4:

```
inCuadriculas = r'C:\Users\...\cuadriculas' #This folder contaings 30 polygons
inLas = r'C:\Users\...\x.lasd' #This is the las dataset that contains 4 las files
outLas = r'C:\Users\...\outLas' #This folder will contain all the 33 .lasd outputs

for las in inCuadriculas: #loop in the folder
    j=2 # variable to rename the future .lasd outputs
    arcpy.ExtractLas_3d(inLas,outLas,"",inCuadriculas,"PROCESS_EXTENT","","MAINTAIN_VLR","REARRANGE_POINTS","NO_COMPUTE_STATS",os.path.join(outLas,"las{0}".format(j)))
    print inCuadriculas # Check the name of the polygons.
```

I get this error:

> Message   File Name   Line    Position     Traceback
>         C:\Users...\clip_las.py    49
>       ExtractLas    c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\ddd.py    2003         ExecuteError:
>   Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Extraction
>   Boundary: Dataset C:\Users...\cuadriculas does not exist or is not
>   supported Failed to execute (ExtractLas).

According to the tool guide in:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/extract-las.htm, the third parameter (extent) is optional.

Comment: The tool name is `ExtractLas`, but in the code you use `ExtractLas_3d`. Why is that?

Comment: You are right, Andre Silva. In the link I show, there is the ExtractLas_3d and ExtractLas nomenclature... I used ExtractLas_3d and I have the result expected.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to run ExtractLas_3d for each of the 30 polygons?

You cant "loop a folder" with `for las in inCuadriculas` since inCuadriculas is a path (string) to a folder. You need to list the polygons with [ListFeatureClasses](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) and then loop over each of the listed polygons:

```
import arcpy
inCuadriculas = r'C:\Users\...\cuadriculas'
inLas = r'C:\Users\...\x.lasd'
outLas = r'C:\Users\...\outLas'

arcpy.env.workspace=inCuadriculas

polylist=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='Polygon')

for polygon in polylist:
    arcpy.ExtractLas_3d(in_las_dataset=inLas, target_folder=outLas, boundary=polygon, 
                        process_entire_files='PROCESS_EXTENT', remove_vlr='MAINTAIN_VLR',
                        rearrange_points='REARRANGE_POINTS', compute_stats='NO_COMPUTE_STATS', 
                        out_las_dataset='Outlas_{0}'.format(polygon))
```

Comment: 1. The first question is because there is another tool? 
2. I am adding 'Outlas_{0}.lasd'.format(polygon)) in order to have a las dataset as a result, but it doesn't work. I tried it manually, and it creates the las dataset.